# There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table that match the referencing column list in the foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE Empleados(
ID_Empleados int identity,
Codigo_Empleado int,
Nombre varchar(50),
Apellido varchar(50),
Telefono varchar(50),
Departamento varchar(50),
Cargo varchar(50),
Fecha_Ingreso date,
Salario int,
Estatus int
)   



 CREATE TABLE Departamentos(
ID_Departamentos int identity,
ID_Empleados int,
Codigo_Departamento int,
Nombre varchar(50),
FOREIGN KEY (ID_Empleados) REFERENCES Empleados(ID_Empleados))


    CREATE TABLE Cargos(
ID_Cargos int identity,
ID_Empleados int,
Cargo varchar(50),
FOREIGN KEY (ID_Empleados) REFERENCES Empleados(ID_Empleados))
```

Quiero relacionar la tabla departamentos y cargos con la tabla empleados, pero cuando lo trato de hacer me sale el error que escribí en el título y no sé que hacer ¿Qué hago para solucionar eso?

Comment: GRACIAS, EXACTAMENTE ERA ESO LO QUE ME FALTABA...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te hace falta tanto en la tabla `Empleados` como así mismo en tu tabla `Departamentos` agregar:

- El símbolo `PRIMARY KEY`

A cada uno de las llaves primarias, lo anterior [lo puedes leer a detalle aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-primary-keys?view=sql-server-ver15#BeforeYouBegin).

Con lo anterior ya debería estar funcionando, sin embargo si lees el segundo punto del enlace que te comparto también indica que debes agregar a cada una de ellas `NOT NULL`

Comment: Exacto, muchisimas gracias hermano, era eso lo que necesitaba.